# Set another Business hour than the time really is

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2017

I have a DateTime dimension with dates like this:

```
Datetime                      Date hour
--------------------------------------
2026-01-01 00:00:00.0000000       24
2025-12-31 23:00:00.0000000       23
2025-12-31 22:00:00.0000000       22
2025-12-31 21:00:00.0000000       21
2025-12-31 20:00:00.0000000       20
2025-12-31 19:00:00.0000000       19
2025-12-31 18:00:00.0000000       18
2025-12-31 17:00:00.0000000       17
2025-12-31 16:00:00.0000000       16
2025-12-31 15:00:00.0000000       15
2025-12-31 14:00:00.0000000       14
2025-12-31 13:00:00.0000000       13
2025-12-31 12:00:00.0000000       12
2025-12-31 11:00:00.0000000       11
2025-12-31 10:00:00.0000000       10
2025-12-31 09:00:00.0000000       9
2025-12-31 08:00:00.0000000       8
2025-12-31 07:00:00.0000000       7
2025-12-31 06:00:00.0000000       6
2025-12-31 05:00:00.0000000       5
2025-12-31 04:00:00.0000000       4
2025-12-31 03:00:00.0000000       3
2025-12-31 02:00:00.0000000       2
2025-12-31 01:00:00.0000000       1
```

Due to systemtime i need that my hours start at 6 o'clock instead, but how do i do that? I could create a temptable with hardcoded values and join on, but theres gotta be a simpler way?

**Desired result:**

```
Datetime                      Date hour
--------------------------------------
2026-01-01 00:00:00.0000000       19
2025-12-31 23:00:00.0000000       18
2025-12-31 22:00:00.0000000       17
2025-12-31 21:00:00.0000000       16
2025-12-31 20:00:00.0000000       15
2025-12-31 19:00:00.0000000       14
2025-12-31 18:00:00.0000000       13
2025-12-31 17:00:00.0000000       12
2025-12-31 16:00:00.0000000       11
2025-12-31 15:00:00.0000000       10
2025-12-31 14:00:00.0000000       9
2025-12-31 13:00:00.0000000       8
2025-12-31 12:00:00.0000000       7
2025-12-31 11:00:00.0000000       6
2025-12-31 10:00:00.0000000       5
2025-12-31 09:00:00.0000000       4
2025-12-31 08:00:00.0000000       3
2025-12-31 07:00:00.0000000       2
2025-12-31 06:00:00.0000000       1
2025-12-31 05:00:00.0000000       24
2025-12-31 04:00:00.0000000       23
2025-12-31 03:00:00.0000000       22
2025-12-31 02:00:00.0000000       21
2025-12-31 01:00:00.0000000       20
```

> And for any questions about why I dont hold a DateDimension and a
>   TimeDimension. This cannot forefill my requirements since I have many
>   more business rules on my datetime dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess...

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET [Date hour] = IIF(DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR, -5, [datetime])) = 0,24,DATEPART(HOUR,DATEADD(HOUR, -5, [datetime]));
```

Comment: Thanks, i just wrote to your in a comment about the datepart stuff. I dont know why i didnt think of this myself. I need to go home - Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Given that your `[Date hour]` column is already computed, you may try updating using the modulus:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET [Date hour] = 1 + ([Date hour] + 18) % 24;
```

### Demo

A better long term solution might be to make your date hour column a computed column, based on the original date time information.  Se the answer by @Larnu for one way to do this.

Comment: Number 5 starts with 0 besides that the rest is ok - And thanks for the help

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot - This is also a great solution :) Appreciate it